# SPARQL query and reasoning to get similar indviduals from two different ontologies

Tags: sparql, jena, owl, virtuoso, rdfs

The first ontology has the following:

**Issue Ontology members(classes):**

```
<http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues#issues>
<http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues#products>
```

Predicate/Properties:

```
<http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues#hasIssues>
```

[image: Issue Ontology]

Triple store for this ontology (raw data), I show it here in Turtle format:

```
@prefix : <http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues> .

:Fido rdf:type :products ,
               owl:NamedIndividual ;

      :productName "FidoProdCEO_12"^^xsd:string ;

      :hasIssues :issue_1239 .

###  http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues#issue_1239

:issue_1239 rdf:type :issues ,
                     owl:NamedIndividual ;

            :issueName "FeatureIssue"^^xsd:string .
```

**The Second ontology has the following:**

Project Ontology members (classes):

```
<http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#GroupProject>
<http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#Project>
<http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#ProjectVersion>
```

Predicate/Properties:

```
<http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#belongsTo>
<http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#dependsOn>
```

[image: Project Ontology diagram]
Triple store for the ontology (raw data), I show it here in Turtle format:

```
@prefix : <http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project> .

###  http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#Apple

:Apple rdf:type :ProjectVersion ,
                owl:NamedIndividual ;

       :hasProjectName "AppleTowandOne"^^xsd:string ;

       :belongsTo :RedBlueCompany .

###  http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#Fido

:Fido rdf:type :ProjectVersion ,
               owl:NamedIndividual ;

      :hasProjectName "FidoProdCEO"^^xsd:string ;

      :dependsOn :Apple .

###  http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#RedBlueCompany

:RedBlueCompany rdf:type :GroupProject ,
                         owl:NamedIndividual ;

                :groupName "RedGroupCompant lmt"^^xsd:string .
```

**Question**

1- I would like to say, project:projectversion from ontology project same as issues:product from ontology issues, is that possible and how?

2- if question (1) is yes, how could I infer the similar individuals from the shared concepts, i.e, if we say projectversion is same as product it does not mean all the individuals are similar, in the example, i would like to automatically infer the individual issues:Fido type of issue:products is same as the individual  prject:Fido type of project:projectversion. From that inferred fact, i would infer automatically that project:Fido issue:hasissue  issues:issues_1239. Finally, I would like to run SPARQL query as follow:

```
SELECT ?product ?issue FROM <namegraph>
WHERE{ 
       ?product issues:hasIssues ?issue.
}
```

The results that I should get as follow:

```
?product                                               ?issue
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<http://www.projectexample.com/ontology/project#Fido>  <http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues#issue_1239>
<http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues#Fido>      <http://www.issueonto.com/ontologies/issues#issue_1239>
```

Comment: More specific, Is is possible to link both ontology based on what I said from the question? or the linked classes should have the same name to be linked?

Comment: I updated the question, hope that clear

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to say, project:projectversion from ontology project same
>   as issues:product from ontology issues, is that possible and how?

All you need is the triple

```
project:projectversion owl:equivalentClass issues:product
```

I don't know how you're combining these ontologies;  whether you're just loading the data from both into a triple store, or creating a third ontology that imports both and loading that (along with its imports) into a triple store, but somewhere you need that axiom.  For a "merging" ontology like this, I'd usually create a third ontology that imports both (but leaving them unchanged) and add the axiom to that third ontology.

> 2- if question (1) is yes, how could I infer the similar individuals
>   from the shared concepts, i.e, if we say projectversion is same as
>   product it does not mean all the individuals are similar, in the
>   example, i would like to automatically infer the individual
>   issues:Fido type of issue:products is same as the individual
>   prject:Fido type of project:projectversion. From that inferred fact, i
>   would infer automatically that project:Fido issue:hasissue
>   issues:issues_1239.

You still have told us what criteria you would use to decide that issues:Fido and project:Fido are the same individual.  The only apparent similarity that they have is the strings "FidoProdCEO_12" and "FidoProdCEO".  Is that what the decision is supposed to be based on?  If so, then you could do something like the following.  I've created a *minimal* amount of data for convenience:

```
@prefix o1: <urn:ex:ont1#> .
@prefix o2: <urn:ex:ont2#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

o1:A a o1:Product ;
     o1:productName "ProductA_1234" ;
     o1:hasIssue o1:issue42 .

o2:B a o2:ProjectVersion ;
     o2:projectName "ProductA" .

o1:Product owl:equivalentClass o2:ProjectVersion .
```

```sql
prefix o1: <urn:ex:ont1#>
prefix o2: <urn:ex:ont2#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?product ?issue where {
  #-- A *product* is something that's an instance of
  #-- o1:Product or another class that's equivalent
  #-- to it.
  ?product a/(owl:equivalentClass|^owl:equivalentClass)* o1:Product

  #-- The issues of a product are any of its
  #-- o1:hasIssue values, or the o1:hasIssue 
  #-- value of any product that has a name
  #-- beginning with its o2:projectName.
  { ?product o1:hasIssue ?issue }
  union
  { ?product o2:projectName ?projectName .
    ?_product o1:productName ?productName ;
              o1:hasIssue ?issue .
    filter strstarts(?productName,?projectName)
  }
}
```

```
------------------------
| product | issue      |
========================
| o2:B    | o1:issue42 |
| o1:A    | o1:issue42 |
------------------------
```

Of course, the fact that you still end up having to examine projectName and productName values means that the equivalent class axiom isn't actually buying you all that much (at least in terms of this query).  That is, it would be sufficient to just ask for "products (and projects with matching names) and their issues."  That is, you get the same results from this query, which is just the second part of the first query:

```sql
prefix o1: <urn:ex:ont1#>
prefix o2: <urn:ex:ont2#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?product ?issue where {
  { ?product o1:hasIssue ?issue }
  union
  { ?product o2:projectName ?projectName .
    ?_product o1:productName ?productName ;
              o1:hasIssue ?issue .
    filter strstarts(?productName,?projectName)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried based on your what you suggest, it gives me the same individuals from the same class, while i could not get see the individuals for the second class, any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: @Josjua Taylor I just updated my question with a complete example

Comment: That is exactly what I want, but this is just string matching queries, am I right?.
How could I enable/leverage the semantic representation on this example, i.e., how could I use the semantic rules to infer the hidden facts between o1:Product  and o2:ProjectVersion where if there are two individuals in both o1:product and o2:ProjectVersion share the same attributes (e.g. names) then they are similar to each other and it means they share the same properties (e.g hasIssues).

Comment: You'd still end up have to do the string matching in order to figure out which things are the same, but once you've done that, you can add owl:sameAs links between the individuals.  You keep saying "similar to each other", and it's really not clear whether you mean "similar to" or "same as".

Comment: yes, sameas leads to similarity, if that is not true please tell me. 
Based on what I read on the semantic web, there are some relations can be asserted in order to establish the sameness. For example, owl:InverseFunctionalPropery, (if A leads to X, and B leads to X) -> then A and B are refer to the samething. Thus, from the example above, o1:A   has o1:issue42, and o2:B has o1:issue24 then, o1:A sameas o2B.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is an owl:equivalentClass relation. To make this work you have to perform the following tasks:

1. Create and RDF document into which you place the owl:equivalentClass relation -- alternatively you can use SPARQL 1.1 INSERT to place the relation into a Virtuoso hosted Named Graph
2. Create an Inference Rule that functions as a Context-Lense when viewing the data in Virtuoso -- be it via SPARQL Query Results of an Entity Description Page etc.

Command (issued via SQL CommandLine of Conductor UI) for associating a Named Graph with an Inference Rule:
RDFS_RULE_SET ('{rule-name}', '{named-graph-uri-or-rdf-document-url}');

Links:

1. [Sample file](http://kingsley.idehen.net/public_home/kidehen/Public/Linked%20Data%20Documents/Tutorials/inference-rule-for-stock-quotes.ttl) (note SQL part is commented out re., Rules and Named Graph association)
2. [Live Example](http://%20%20[1]:%20http://kingsley.idehen.net/public_home/kidehen/Public/Linked%20Data%20Documents/Tutorials/inference-rule-for-stock-quotes.ttl%20%20%20[2]:%20http://kidehen.blogspot.com/2014/02/class-equivalence-based-reasoning.html) -- showcasing owl:equivalentClass reasoning via Schema.org, FOAF, and GoodRelations ontologies.